# how can I make XML print multiple listings?

Tags: php, xml

I've got an XML file that is being called by AJAX and it only prints 1 listing of a key while there are multiple listings of that particular key!

here's the link to the XML page - http://smartliving.comule.com/smartliving.xml

here's the PHP code -

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("smartliving.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('ORIGIN');

for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++)
{
//Process only element nodes
if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1)
  {
  if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q)
    {
    $y=($x->item($i)->parentNode);
    }
  }
}

$cd=($y->childNodes);

for ($i=0;$i<$cd->length;$i++)
{
//Process only element nodes
if ($cd->item($i)->nodeType==1)
  {
  echo("<b>" . $cd->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
  echo($cd->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
  echo("<br>");
  }
}
?>
```

Here's the HTML code to the site as well - URL: http://smartliving.comule.com/example.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showCD(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getprod.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="cds" onchange="showCD(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a CD:</optioSelect a CD:
n>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="txtHint"><b>CD info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

if I make a selection - say "Thailand", "India", or "China", it only reads one product item when it should search through the 250 products that there are and print out the ones that are manufactured in the respective countries!

Say, when I pick "Thailand" - it only prints ONE product listing - whereas there are many products that are made in Thailand!

P-CATEGORY: Handle and Knobs
P-TYPE: Unflash Handle
P-SPECS: Steel Handle
P-NAME: Simon Two Gang
P-BRAND: Simon
ORIGIN: Thailand
DIMENSION: 44 inches
WEIGHT: 1 kg
QTY_x002F_PACK: 55
MORE_x0020_INFO: afklja fkadfj lkdfjad

What do you make of this? how can I solve this problem and make it print ALL the THAI products in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your search loop only stores the **LAST** matching node, which means that all earlier matched nodes are simply discarded/ignored. You need to combine the loops, so that as soon as you find a matching node, you start doing the second loop, e.g:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++) {
    //Process only element nodes
    if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
       if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
          $y = $x->item($i)->parentNode;
          for ($j = 0; $j < $y->childNodes->length; $j++) {
             //echoes go here
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: still giving me errors ...saying i can't use echo where u placed the statement "// echoes go here"